# Object.keys to iterate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am currently using two kinds of iterations in my code:

For objects (snippet 1):

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do stuff with key and obj[key]
    }
}
```

For arrays (snippet 2):

```
for (var i=0, count=arr.length;i<count;i++) {
    // do stuff with i and arr[i]
}
```

I'd like to simplify my code and use a single function for both objects and arrays (snippet 3):

```
var keys=Object.keys(arrorobj);
for (var i=0, count=keys.length;i<count;i++) {
    // do stuff with keys[i] and arrorobj[keys[i]]
}
```

I know that the snippet 3 is fine for objects, but is it also going to work as I expect with arrays, and replace both snippets 1 and 2? In particular, can I be assured that in all browsers (well, at least those that support Object.keys) snippet 3 will respect the key order (up from index 0)?

[edit] I plan to use this in particular for deep merge of objects. My current code is heavy as at each level I have 3 branches depending on the type (array, object or other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work while the only enumerable properties on your array are the numbered slots (the default of an `Array`), but it doesn't make a guarantee of the ordering of the returned properties, as they're defined to be in `for ( in )` order, which doesn't always iterate numerically (depending on how the properties were assigned).

If you assigned another property, it'd also be enumerated (this wouldn't happen with a more standard iteration technique).

It also wouldn't behave quite the same for empty slots (e.g. `new Array(25)`), as the `for` loop would iterate over these.

It is generally recommended to use a `for` loop for an Array, or `forEach()` method (or related).

Comment: thanks! Would you have a simple example to show me that iterates array indexes in the wrong order? I have often heard this warning, but never seen it happen in practice...

Comment: @Christophe This is a good start: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: well, this example actually goes in the right direction (for me) as it respects the numerical order. I would be more worried about the opposite (and my concern is really for arrays)